# Bind to parent within XAML property declaration?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to bind to a property while inside a XAML 'property setter'. Binding at this location does not seem to happen in the same hierarchy as binding at a 'normal' place. Does anyone know how to bind something there?

I've also tried using RelativeSource to get the parent (which is better, since that's what I actually want to do, not duplicate it) but no dice.

```
<loc:MyType Target="{Binding ElementName=Editor, Path=TextArea, Converter={loc:EditorAdapterConverter}}">
    <loc:MyType.PopupActions>
        <loc:BackspaceHideAction Target="{Binding ElementName=Editor, Path=TextArea, Converter={loc:EditorAdapterConverter}}" /> //Binding doesn't work
        <loc:KeyAction Action="Show" Key="Space" Modifiers="LeftCtrl" />
        <loc:KeyAction Action="Hide" Key="Escape" />
    </loc:MyType.PopupActions>
</loc:MyType>
```

Relevant information: `BackspaceHideAction` inherits from `FrameworkElement` and has a dependency property called Target (actually same as `MyType`). I need to access this `Target` also in `BackspaceHideAction` - it doesn't really have to be a DP property there as well.

`MyType.PopupActions` is a dependency property on MyType declared as a `PopupActionList : List<PopupAction>`.

I am currently assuming that the reason I can't bind is that I am nested inside a property instantiation. Similar binding have worked elsewhere (just the line above) so the type of binding shouldn't be the problem. Just the context.

Comment: You who downvoted and voted for close - why? It would help me improve the question (unless you find it so reprehensible as to render it irredeemable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing a little further testing, I've discovered why it didn't work.

The dependency property `PopupActions` on `MyType` was declared as a `PopupActionList` - nothing fancy. But properties aren't automatically entered into the 'DOM'-like structure of WPF elements, which isn't that surprising (after you figure it out, as always).

However, with some added code to call `MyType.AddLogicalChild` with each individual PopupAction as the item, everything works fine! (so far)